# Firefox 89 light theme conflict with Plata

Tags: 20.04, gnome, firefox, themes

I have this possibly simple issue with the [Plata theme](https://gitlab.com/tista500/plata-theme/) and `Firefox 89` Light theme. The minimise, maximise and close buttons are almost of the same colour as the toolbar and are not visible while using the `Plata` theme in `20.04`

[image]

minus, box and X should have been displayed here.  But not visible at all.

simple question, where do `themes` - in general, store images for these ? What names do they have ? Thanks.